# Proper way to get aggregates in Domain Driven Design

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

In a `DDD` architecture, I have an `Order` aggregate root and a `Product` aggregate. When I want to add a `Product` to a specific `Order`, I do:

```
class Order
{
  void AddProduct(Product p)
  {
    this.Products = p;
  }
}
```

Then, `OrderRepository` persists the in-memory `Order.Products` colleciton to the database.

My question is: how can I get a specific `Product` for a specific `Order`? Given that we should not inject repositories into entities, I am not sure how to hydrate the in-memory `Order.Products` collection:

```
class Order
{
  Product GetProduct(int productID)
  {
    return this.Products.Where(x => x.ProductID == productID);
  }
}
```

Or is this something that belongs to the `OrderRepository`?

Comment: If you are talking about hydrating a specific Product object from the database, it should be a method on the repository.

Comment: Thanks, that was my question. Should I hydrate the Product object from the repository or the Order class? I think it's clear to me now that it should go to the repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Order
{
    void AddProduct(Product p)
    {
        this.Products = p;
    }
}
```

This model is probably wrong.

(1) If the state of `Product` needs to satisfy the business invariant in `Order`, then `Product` should be an entity within the Order aggregate but not also a separate aggregate of its own.

On the other hand, if `Order` doesn't need to know anything about the state of `Product` to satisfy its own invariants, then the Products collection should not contain products, but something else (probably `Id<Product>`)

*Hint: does it make any sense to edit a `Product` by changing the `Order` ?*

(2) Most discussions of `Order` aggregates reach the conclusion that the order holds a collection of `OrderItems` (note: not aggregates), where each `OrderItem` holds a *reference* to the Product aggregate.

Shopping carts are a fairly common example case in DDD discussions

Comment: Thank you! That was really, really insightful.

Answer (score 3):

I know that this question has an accepted answer but I'll give my opinion anyway :)

An Aggregate Root (AR) should never reference another AR.  It only ever uses either just the Id of the related AR or a Value Object (VO) that contains the Id of the related AR along with some optional extra data.

The interesting thing about the `Order` -> `Product` relationship is that it is a typical many-to-many relation in database terms.  In the database world one would model that, typically, by creating an association (or link) table called `OrderProduct` and add columns for any data related to the association, such as quantity and price.  However, somehow the table we all use is called `OrderItem` or `OrderLine`.  We do this because it makes sense to have the association closer to the order.

I have a blog post around this that still holds somewhat true: http://www.ebenroux.co.za/design/2009/09/08/many-to-many-aggregate-roots/

In the DDD world we would then not have our `Order` keep a list of object references to `Product` instances.  Instead we would create a VO called `OrderItem` that contains only the `ProductId` along with the `Quantity`, `Price`, and a denormalized `ProductDescription` since that description may change after the order has been placed and, historically, that would change what was ordered which would be a no-no.

Just some food for thought :)